# Collocated Query Processing in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

(Q1) Is it the right way to configure the cache for collocated processing in Apache Ignite:

```
    RendezvousAffinityFunction affFunc = new RendezvousAffinityFunction();        
    affFunc.setExcludeNeighbors(true);              
    affFunc.setPartitions(4);

    CacheConfiguration<Long, EMP> cache1 = new CacheConfiguration<>(EMP_CACHE);
    cache1.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, EMP.class);
    cache1.setSqlFunctionClasses(EMPFunctions.class);
    cache1.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cache1.setAffinity(affFunc);
```

(Q2) Suppose, I have 2 Node, 2 Dataset, 4 Partitions for each dataset (cache1, cache2). So, after partitioning the data, Node1 contains 2 partitions (p1, p3) for each dataset and Node2 contains (p2 and p4) for each dataset. I need to know how is collocated join query executed in this scenario. More Specifically, As Node1 contains p1 and p3 partitions for both dataset, how does Ignite join p1, p2(cache1) with p1, p2(cache2)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join Query in Apache Ignite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602842/join-query-in-apache-ignite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about SQL joins, they are by default only executed locally, that is, joining does not cross the node boundary. This works by splitting query into "map" and "reduce" parts, and joins are executed during "map" on individual nodes.

You can override this behavior by setting `distributedJoins` to `true`. If you are sure that your data is always joined and grouped per partinity, you can set `collocated` to `true`. These are SQL options which can be set on `JDBC` `Connection`, `SqlFieldsQuery`, etc...

So in your case, you are right, Ignite joins p1, p2(cache1) with p1, p2(cache2). And then it will merge query results from Node1 and Node2.

Comment: I am using SQLFieldQuery. The query works fine in multiple nodes. I am little worry about the return result. Also, I need to partition the data manually. That's why I need to know how Ignite performs SQL joins in each node, as the data are in different partitions. For any distributed systems, there are some methods to perform a join query among partitioned data. thanks.

Comment: @faring as I said you can set `distributedJoins`, but performance might suffer.

Answer (score 0):

You already asked a similar question: [Join Query in Apache Ignite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602842/join-query-in-apache-ignite/52603948)

There is no correspondence between partitions of different caches. You can use an [affinity key](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#section-collocate-data-with-data) to collocate data between caches. In most cases you shouldn't care about the partition ids of your data. Only collocation with other data entries matter.

Moreover, it's not recommended to set such low number of partitions. Rendezvous affinity function doesn't guarantee, that partitions will be distributed evenly between nodes, because it works based on a hash code. Only approximate equality of partition numbers is guaranteed. So, I would recommend to go with the default value, which is 1024 for partitioned caches and 512 for replicated.

Comment: Thanks, @Denis. For any distributed system, there are rules to perform SQL join query in partitioned data. I want to know how Ignite does that in each node. This is because I need to partition the data manually for each partition. Thanks again.